# if a column is empty, i want to populate the column with data from another source

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Below is an example table

Im trying to figure out the best way to populate the address when they are missing. I have my main table and i'll be able to join onto another table using the postcode.

Im just not sure what the best sytax would be as im dealing with "" and not nulls.

**Main Table**

| Address | PostTown | Postcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Elf road | CASTLETON ROAD | SS9 XCY |
| Mac Road | FLEETWOOD ROAD | DS9 X11 |
| Fulham road | BASILDONROAD | SC9 R55 |
|  | WALTHAM ROAD | SV9 D72 |
|  | BROXBURN ROAD | SA9 X2X |

**Left join table**

| Address | postcode |
| --- | --- |
| Station approach | SA9 X2X |
| Rosebay Gardens | SV9 D72 |
| Fulham road | SC9 R55 |
| Mac Road | DS9 X11 |
| Elf road | SS9 XCY |

Comment: Any of these answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

> Im just not sure what the best sytax would be as im dealing with "" and not nulls.

Consider below

```
select if(t1.Address = '', t2.Address, t1.Address) as Address, t1.PostTown, t1.Postcode
from Main_Table t1
left join Lookup_Table t2
using (Postcode)
```

Comment: have you tried? did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JOIN statement. In this case I get the fields from both tables. If one field is null this query shows the field in blank.

You can see this example:

```
SELECT B.Address,A.PostTown,A.Postcode FROM `[project-name].[dataset-name].table_main` A
left join `[project-name].[dataset-name].table1` B on (A.Postcode=B.postcode)
```

This query validates the fields B.Address and A.PostTown if they are nulls. If one field is null, you can put the text that you want.

You can see this example:

```
with main as (
SELECT B.Address,A.PostTown,A.Postcode FROM `[project-name].[dataset-name].table_main` A
left join `[project-name].[dataset-name].table1` B on (A.Postcode=B.postcode)
)
 
select IFNULL(main.Address,'information missing') as Address,IFNULL(main.PostTown,'information missing'),main.PostCode from main
order by Address desc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use Coalesce to replace wioth B.Address if A.Address is null

```
SELECT Coalesce(A.Address,B.Address) Address,A.PostTown,A.Postcode FROM `[project-name].[dataset-name].table_main` A
left join `[project-name].[dataset-name].table1` B on (A.Postcode=B.postcode)
```